# Converting windows Form to windows Metro Form

Tags: c#, forms, microsoft-metro, windows-forms-designer

i have written a desktop app in normal windows form, it worked fine. Later i tried to convert it to Metro form because of its modern look. With minor change in control names i used most of the code from old normal form. But the form resizing function block throwing "System.NullReferenceException" while starting the app. But after commenting the resizing event it works fine.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    defaultSize = this.Size;
    panel4Size = new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(panel4.Location.X, panel4.Location.Y, panel4.Width, panel4.Height), new Rectangle(qusNo.Location.X, qusNo.Location.Y, qusNo.Width, qusNo.Height), new Rectangle(element1.Location.X, element1.Location.Y, element1.Width, element1.Height), new Rectangle(element2.Location.X, element2.Location.Y, element2.Width, element2.Height), new Rectangle(operation.Location.X, operation.Location.Y, operation.Width, operation.Height), new Rectangle(line.Location.X, line.Location.Y, line.Width, line.Height), new Rectangle(nextQus.Location.X, nextQus.Location.Y, nextQus.Width, nextQus.Height), new Rectangle(flp1.Location.X, flp1.Location.Y, flp1.Width, flp1.Height), new Rectangle(flp2.Location.X, flp2.Location.Y, flp2.Width, flp2.Height), new Rectangle(opt1.Location.X, opt1.Location.Y, opt1.Width, opt1.Height), new Rectangle(opt2.Location.X, opt2.Location.Y, opt2.Width, opt2.Height), new Rectangle(opt3.Location.X, opt3.Location.Y, opt3.Width, opt3.Height), new Rectangle(opt4.Location.X, opt4.Location.Y, opt4.Width, opt4.Height), new Rectangle(opt5.Location.X, opt5.Location.Y, opt5.Width, opt5.Height), new Rectangle(opt6.Location.X, opt6.Location.Y, opt6.Width, opt6.Height), new Rectangle(dopt1.Location.X, dopt1.Location.Y, dopt1.Width, dopt1.Height), new Rectangle(dopt2.Location.X, dopt2.Location.Y, dopt2.Width, dopt2.Height), new Rectangle(dopt3.Location.X, dopt3.Location.Y, dopt3.Width, dopt3.Height), new Rectangle(dopt4.Location.X, dopt4.Location.Y, dopt4.Width, dopt4.Height), new Rectangle(dopt5.Location.X, dopt5.Location.Y, dopt5.Width, dopt5.Height), new Rectangle(dopt6.Location.X, dopt6.Location.Y, dopt6.Width, dopt6.Height), new Rectangle(LaBackBt.Location.X, LaBackBt.Location.Y, LaBackBt.Width, LaBackBt.Height), new Rectangle(LaFinishBt.Location.X, LaFinishBt.Location.Y, LaFinishBt.Width, LaFinishBt.Height), new Rectangle(results.Location.X, results.Location.Y, results.Width, results.Height) };
    panel2Size = new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(panel2.Location.X, panel2.Location.Y, panel2.Width, panel2.Height), new Rectangle(Easy.Location.X, Easy.Location.Y, Easy.Width, Easy.Height), new Rectangle(Hard.Location.X, Hard.Location.Y, Hard.Width, Hard.Height), new Rectangle(MdBackBt.Location.X, MdBackBt.Location.Y, MdBackBt.Width, MdBackBt.Height), new Rectangle(eelem1.Location.X, eelem1.Location.Y, eelem1.Width, eelem1.Height), new Rectangle(eelem2.Location.X, eelem2.Location.Y, eelem2.Width, eelem2.Height), new Rectangle(eelem3.Location.X, eelem3.Location.Y, eelem3.Width, eelem3.Height), new Rectangle(eelem4.Location.X, eelem4.Location.Y, eelem4.Width, eelem4.Height), new Rectangle(eelem5.Location.X, eelem5.Location.Y, eelem5.Width, eelem5.Height), new Rectangle(flp3.Location.X, flp3.Location.Y, flp3.Width, flp3.Height), new Rectangle(flp4.Location.X, flp4.Location.Y, flp4.Width, flp4.Height), new Rectangle(flp5.Location.X, flp5.Location.Y, flp5.Width, flp5.Height), new Rectangle(flp6.Location.X, flp6.Location.Y, flp6.Width, flp6.Height) };
    panel1Size = new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(panel1.Location.X, panel1.Location.Y, panel1.Width, panel1.Height), new Rectangle(label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y, label1.Width, label1.Height), new Rectangle(listView3.Location.X, listView3.Location.Y, listView3.Width, listView3.Height), new Rectangle(HmAdd.Location.X, HmAdd.Location.Y, HmAdd.Width, HmAdd.Height), new Rectangle(HmSub.Location.X, HmSub.Location.Y, HmSub.Width, HmSub.Height), new Rectangle(HmMul.Location.X, HmMul.Location.Y, HmMul.Width, HmMul.Height), new Rectangle(HmDiv.Location.X, HmDiv.Location.Y, HmDiv.Width, HmDiv.Height) };
}

private void reziseChildControl()
{
    Control[] controlP4 = new Control[] { panel4, qusNo, element1, element2, operation, line, nextQus, flp1, flp2, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5, opt6, dopt1, dopt2, dopt3, dopt4, dopt5, dopt6, LaBackBt, LaFinishBt, results };
    Control[] controlP2 = new Control[] { panel2, Easy, Hard, MdBackBt, eelem1, eelem2, eelem3, eelem4, eelem5, flp3, flp4, flp5, flp6 };
    Control[] controlP1 = new Control[] { panel1, label1, listView3, HmAdd, HmSub, HmMul, HmDiv};
    for (int j = 0; j < controlP4.Length; j++)
    {
        resizeControls(panel4Size[j], controlP4[j]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < controlP2.Length; j++)
    {
        resizeControls(panel2Size[j], controlP2[j]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < controlP1.Length; j++)
    {
        resizeControls(panel1Size[j], controlP1[j]);
    }

    }
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reziseChildControl();
    }

    private void resizeControls(Rectangle originalContrl, Control control)
    {
        float xRatio = (float)(this.Width) / (float)(defaultSize.Width);
        float yRatio = (float)(this.Height) / (float)(defaultSize.Height);
        int newX = (int)(originalContrl.X * xRatio);
        int newY = (int)(originalContrl.Y * yRatio);
        int newWidth = (int)(originalContrl.Width * xRatio);
        int newHeight = (int)(originalContrl.Height * yRatio);
        control.Location = new Point(newX, newY);
        control.Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
    }
}
```

**Update**: The NullReferenceException throwing because the Form1_Resize event occurs before Form1_Load event. Form1_Resize event shouldn't be called before i change the layout of window(by dragging or maximize the window size). But Resize event calling automatically at starting of the app before Form1 completely laading. On checking the Form1 property i could not find relevant property which could be the reason for calling resize event while starting. Tried selecting different values for the form1 layout properties, nothing much changes except WindowState propety. Even with different values for WindowState property the Resize event calling at starting.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException at this function call resizeControls(panel4Size[j], controlP4[j]);

Answer (score 0):

its easy to see what value is going null with debugger that is the problem when you create your panelsize don't set whit any start value that going null, to
see these complete guide and examples for build metro style app

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380

hope that helps !!!

Comment: just checked in debugger mode. It works fine. but not in normal mode. strange

Answer (score 0):

Added a simple condition statement to resizing code. It worked fine after that. But didn't able to figure it out exactly what caused calling form_resize event at starting. May be its add in in metro framework but not sure.

Thanks